# How to use temp table in tableau custom sql

Tags: tableau-api

I am using temp table to get the result for tableu visualisation using custom sql:

```
  SELECT *,

case when month(startdate) = month(enddate) then 'Y' else 'N' end as SameMonth,

into #temp

FROM t1


select a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h

from #temp where SameMonth = 'Y'

union

select a,b,c,d,e,k,l,m

from #temp where SameMonth = 'N'
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @AlexBlakemore Hi I want to create a temp table in Tableau to get the data from the database table for tableau connection the query is similar to above.

Comment: Temp table definitions go in the "Initial SQL" box, not the main query